# Let ReactJS mixins require an external module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins

I know we should avoid using `mixins` , but let's use it for this case.

I defined a few logging in/out functions as a `mixins` module and I require it in a number of components.

```
var loginStore = require('../../stores/LoginStore'); // this is the problem ?
var AuthMixins = {
    statics: {
        willTransitionTo(transition) {
            console.log(loginStore.id);
            if (!loginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
                transition.redirect('login');
            }
        }
    },
    _getLoginState() {
        return {
            userLoggedIn: loginStore.isLoggedIn()
        };
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeListener = this._onChange;
        loginStore.addChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    },
    _onChange() {
        this.setState(this._getLoginState());
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            userLoggedIn: this._getLoginState()
        };
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        loginStore.removeChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    }
};
module.exports = AuthMixins;
```

LoginStore.js :

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/AppDispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var LoginStore = (function() {
    var _cred = null,
        _user = null,
        id = Date.now();
    var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    var _listenToLogin = function(action) {
        if (action.actionType === 'LOGIN_USER') {
            _cred = action.cred;
            _user = action.user;
            eventEmitter.emit('CHANGE');
        } else if (action.actionType === 'LOGOUT_USER') {
            _cred = null;
            _user = null;
            eventEmitter.emit('CHANGE');
        }
    };
    AppDispatcher.register(_listenToLogin.bind(this));
    var user = function() {
        return _user;
    };
    var cred = function() {
        return _cred;
    };
    var addChangeListener = function(cb) {
        eventEmitter.on('CHANGE', cb);
    };
    var removeChangeListener = function(cb) {
        eventEmitter.removeListener('CHANGE', cb);
    };
    var isLoggedIn = function() {
        return (!!_user);
    };
    return ({
        id: id,
        user: user,
        cred: cred,
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
        addChangeListener: addChangeListener,
        removeChangeListener: removeChangeListener
    });
})();
module.exports = LoginStore;
```

As you can see I want LoginStore to be Singleton , so when I access it from different parts of the code , it has the same state.

The following is how I use `mixins` :

About.js :

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var AuthMixins = require('./mixins/LoginMixins');

var About = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'About',
    mixins: [AuthMixins],
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            message: 'Default Prop for About page'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
        {this.props.message}
        </div>);
    }
});

module.exports = About;
```

Now, the problem is that every time `About` is loaded , a new instance of `LoginStore` is loaded. (not respecting this fact that we want it to be singleton) in return it shows that the user is not logged in.

Comment: I think that the issue is that your store is in an IIF, therefore every time you require it, the function is called and the values are reset.

Comment: @gcedo What do you mean by IFF here? would you please clarify it ?

Comment: It's an Immediately Invoked Function. As it is called every time the module is required, it is executed and resets the values.